# Why does my method always reference the first param it receives

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-glide

Can anyone explain this problem to me which occurs when using Java 8 features in Android?

I have a non-static method which accepts a Runnable param. Displays an animation with Glide and when it finishes it runs the param Runnable. The problem is, if I call it more than once with lambdas, it repeats the first runnable each time.

**The method**

```
void wrapActionWithLoaderAnim(@NonNull Runnable postAction) {
    Glide.with(loaderView.getContext())
            .asGif()
            .load(R...)
            .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
            .into(new ImageViewTarget<GifDrawable>(loaderImageView) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(@Nullable GifDrawable resource) {
                    loaderImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    postAction.run();
                }
            });
}
```

**The Calls**

```
wrapActionWithLoaderAnim(() -> {  Log.d(TAG, "Action A"); });
wrapActionWithLoaderAnim(() -> {  Log.d(TAG, "Action B"); });
wrapActionWithLoaderAnim(() -> {  Log.d(TAG, "Action C"); });
```

**The Logcat**

```
Action A
Action A
Action A
```

It may be related to the way the glide chain works, but I feel like I'm missing something fundamental and simple here, but I've been staring at it for too long

Comment: If you switch to regular `Runnable` instances, rather than lambdas, does the behavior change? If the behavior remains the same, my guess is that this is a Glide thing.

Comment: My guess would be that the `wrapActionWithLoaderAnim` method registers the given runnable somewhere, and if it is already set, subsequent calls are silently ignored.

Comment: It does appear to be with Glide, but I'm using a new ImageViewTarget each time so I can't be sure why it would be a problem. Since it's the same resource each time, I can only assume there is some sort of related caching